# Adding images with PaintCode into Xcode 7 using Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, paintcode

I am trying to move a swift file that I exported from PaintCode 2 into my project. I did the following.

1. Exported the project via PaintCode
2. Moved the file into Xcode
3. On my storyboard I put a UIView
4. Clicked on the newly created UIView and selected the class that I imported from PaintCode.

Now I am looking a white box:

[image]

Now the file I got from PaintCode was of type NSObject which I knew couldn't be right so I changed it to UImage. Still getting the same result.

---------UPDATE-----------

I created a new Cococa Class of type UIView, and did the following:

```
@IBDesignable
class CareerButtonClass: UIView {

    //CareerButton.drawCanvas2()
     func drawCareerButton() {
        CareerButton.drawCanvas2()
    }
}
```

Then I named the custom class on IUView in the storyboard CareerButtonClass.

[image]

Here are what my files look like:
[image]

Still getting the same result.

Comment: If you share the project, I may help on finding what the issue is. I use PaintCode @ my workplace everyday + latest Swift without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

For those who run by this post I finally found a good example here:

[PaintCode Tutorial for Developers (Swift 2.0): Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92972/paintcode-tutorial-for-developers-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

That's because PaintCode exports a class with a collection of methods that you can use to draw the content.

Depending on the methods you choose, it can either generate a UIImage for you or you can call the code to draw in the current context.

It's up to you to implement where to use those methods.

Comment: please see my update. Its the implementation that is getting me. Only Objective-C has available examples, and even in example it say, this is different in Swift but doesn't go any further.

Comment: Now try calling `drawCanvas2` on the `drawRect:` function of your view.

Answer (score 0):

The class you got from PaintCode is `NSObject` and it’s right. StyleKit is a collection of all graphics you use in your app.

To render the button, you need to override `drawRect` method in your `UIView`. And call the method to draw the Career Button.

```
@IBDesignable
class CareerButtonClass: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        StyleKit.drawCareerButton()
    }
}
```

See [PaintCode FAQ #29](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/faq#q29).